# WPF DataGrid*Column: set EditingElementStyle

Tags: wpf, datagrid, styles

I'm trying to modify the default style of DataGrid*Column. But it seems that the style is not used by DataGrid.

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridTextColumn_EditStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" >
    <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="Red" />
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridTextColumn}">
    <Setter Property="EditingElementStyle" Value="{StaticResource DataGridTextColumn_EditStyle}" />
</Style>
```

This way it shouldn't be necessary to set the style in DataGrid.Columns.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to define default `Style` for `DataGridTextColumn` because [DataGridTextColumn class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtextcolumn%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) is not [FrameworkElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.aspx) so it doesn't have `Style` property.